# Find actual line number of line after a match

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I want to edit some lines in an XML file.  These lines will all look identical to begin with, they're just part of a block that comes after some other unique line, like:

```
First_Object
... some number of lines
<STATUS>true</STATUS>
... some number of lines
Second_Object
... some number of lines
<STATUS>true</STATUS>
... some number of lines
Third_Object
... some number of lines
<STATUS>true</STATUS>
... some number of lines
```

So, for each of First_Object, Second_Object, Third-Object, etc. I need to get the actual line number of true so I can change that value to some other value.

I started with "grep First_Object -A 100 filename | grep -n '[STATUS]'" (had to use square brackets instead of angles on this site) but that gave me the number of lines after First_Object, not the line number in question.  I know I could add the two together, but that seems messy... there's got to be a way to get "the first occurrence of the string '[STATUS]' after the string 'First_Object' or something similar.

Thanks!

Comment: This is almost certainly the wrong way to handle your XML data. Can you give some more information about the way it is structured and what the selection criteria are? There are dedicated XML-handling tools that are better suited to this sort of processing.

Comment: The XML is a STIG checklist, and as there's no SCAP content for OS X, I'm scripting as much of it as possible.  There is no tool (yet) that will do what I need.

Comment: There doesn't need to be a tool for the special flavor of XML-derived format you're handling; at a basic level, it's still XML. If you want to replace a `STATUS` node that's part of a specific node, the way to do that is to select it by XPath and modify it with a tool like `xmlstarlet`. I could show you how if I knew more about what your XML looks like.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, parsing XML is best left to an XML parser, but if you really have something as literally structured as your example data, something like this might help:

```
$ cat jo.awk
/_Object/ { obj = $0 }
/<STATUS>true<\/STATUS>/ { print obj ": line " NR ": " $0 }

bash-3.2$ cat jo.txt
First_Object
... some number of lines
<STATUS>true</STATUS>
... some number of lines
Second_Object
... some number of lines
<STATUS>true</STATUS>
... some number of lines
Third_Object
... some number of lines
<STATUS>true</STATUS>
... some number of lines

bash-3.2$ awk -f jo.awk jo.txt
First_Object: line 3: <STATUS>true</STATUS>
Second_Object: line 7: <STATUS>true</STATUS>
Third_Object: line 11: <STATUS>true</STATUS>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '/^(First|Second|Third)/,/^<STATUS>/{/^<STATUS>/=}' file
```

This finds ranges of lines between lines beginning with `First or Second or Third` and the string `<STATUS>` and prints the line number of the line containing `<STATUS>`.